# the quicksort program sorts but never stops

Tags: c#, quicksort

[the program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceU6c.jpg)

this is my first time implementing a quick sort application in c#  and I think it works but it does not have a  way out so it keeps looping recursively can anyone help and tell me how to fix this program without destroying and rebuild technique?
and here is the code:

```
using System;
namespace quickso2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = { 12, 3, 1, 45, 16, 91, 21, 38 ,443,1212,53,2,1,0};
            sort ob = new sort();
            Console.WriteLine("before Sorting: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i]+ "  ");
            }

            ob.quicksorting(arr, -1, arr.Length - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("\n after Sorting: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i]+"  "  );
            }
        }
    }
    class sort
    {
        public int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high)
        {
            for (int i = low+1; i < high; i++)
            {

                if (arr[i] < arr[high])
                {
                    low++;
                    swap(ref arr[low], ref arr[i]);
                }
            }
            swap(ref arr[high], ref arr[low + 1]);
            //displaying sorting steps
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int l = 0; l < arr.Length; l++) { 
            Console.Write(arr[l]+"  ");

            }
            return low + 1;
        }
        public void swap(ref int x, ref int y)
        {
            int temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
        }
         public void quicksorting(int[] arr, int low, int high)
        {
            int pivot ;
            if (low < high)
            {
                pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
                quicksorting(arr, -1, pivot - 1);
                quicksorting(arr, pivot + 1, arr.Length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least the recursive calls to quicksort are incorrect as they do not honor low/high. Go back to the algorithm and check the implementation of such.

Comment: You should do the algorithm on paper and then use a debugger and check where it does not do what you expect. In fact, if you run the program and then break into the debugger while in the infinite loop and trace code from that point, it should be relatively obvious which condition is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to the array index being passed in the calls to the quick-sort function.

**Causes of the problem of the infinite loop:**

```
  ob.quicksorting(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);          // In main method

  quicksorting(arr, -1, pivot - 1);               // Recursive call #1

  quicksorting(arr, pivot + 1, arr.Length - 1);   // Recursive call #2
```

**Here is the working solution, with the updated array indices:**

```
using System;
namespace quickso2 {

  public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            int[] arr = { 12, 3, 1, 45, 16, 91, 21, 38 ,443,1212,53,2,1,0};
            sort ob = new sort();
            Console.WriteLine("before Sorting: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write(arr[i]+ "  ");
            }
            ob.quicksorting(arr, 0, arr.Length-1);
            Console.WriteLine("\n after Sorting: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write(arr[i]+"  "  );
            }
        }
  }

  class sort {
        public int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
            int pivot = arr[low];
            while (true) {
                while (arr[low] < pivot) {
                    low++;
                }

                while (arr[high] > pivot) {
                    high--;
                }

                if (low < high) {
                    if (arr[low] == arr[high]) return high;
                    int temp = arr[low];
                    arr[low] = arr[high];
                    arr[high] = temp;
                }
                else {
                    return high;
                }
            }
        }

        public void quicksorting(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
            if (low < high) {
                int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);
                if (pivot > 1) {
                    quicksorting(arr, low, pivot - 1);
                }
                if (pivot + 1 < high) {
                    quicksorting(arr, pivot + 1, high);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
before Sorting: 
12  3  1  45  16  91  21  38  443  1212  53  2  1  0  
 after Sorting: 
0  1  1  2  3  12  16  21  38  45  53  91  443  1212
```